# could find method implementation

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I just started to learn about Android Studio and when I try to install it, it gives me this:

> Error:Could not find method implementation() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

I would really appreciate it if you guys can help me figure this out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. please search "SDK Manager" in the search tool of your Windows machine
2. In the window that will open go at the very end - "Extras" section - [check the following screenshot] and install that package

[image: ]]